# Diff between Simulink models .slx

Tags: git, matlab, diff, simulink

I am using Git and I am using MATLAB/Simulink.

I know that there is some kind of integration in the new versions of MATLAB/Simulink with Git but I was wondering if there is an easy way to read a `git diff` between 2 Simulink models which are of the format `.slx`

This can be useful when, for example, you have a simulink model in which you have a so-called MATLAB Embedded Function and you want to understand what the differences are between the functions in different versions of your software.

It can be also useful to understand the blocks which were commented and all the differences between two different `Simulink` models (`.slx`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

1. If you are in your repository you MUST have a `.git` folder.
2. Go to this folder and open the file  `config` (create it if it is not available, but it should be there normally).
3. Add the following code to the file:

   ```
   [diff "slx"]
   textconv = unzip -c -a
   ```
4. Then you need to create or modify the file `REPOSITORY/.gitattributes` and add:

   ```
   *.slx diff=slx
   ```

In this way when you do a `git diff` on a Simulink model (`.slx`) you will have a quite readable result.

I hope it will help someone else.

Comment: MathWorks also offer a model comparison through XML files generated from the models using Simulink Report Generator, see: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/rptgenext/model-comparison.html

Comment: Yes I know. To use that you should go the creation of a so-called SIMULINK project. I didn't want to do that. But it is just a matter of taste.

Comment: This might work, but as the Simulink file format is not documented, you run the risk of it not working when you switch version/release or when you compare two models created in different releases of MATLAB.

Comment: Upvote on this, it's amazing... :)  Is there any way to do this for direct file viewing of the folder as well?  Doing this with Git Extensions works perfectly to have it unzip when using the built-in diff tool, but when viewing the file directly, it does not unzip first...

Answer (score 3):

Whilst a text comparison can give some idea of what has changed for simple changes, the information that goes to into a Simulink model is stored in a variety of places with the SLX container. A tool like the Simulink Comparison features within the Simulink Report Generator can give much more insight into what has changed, as well as allowing operations like merge.

Simulink has had Git integration, via a Simulink Project, since R2014a, or via the MATLAB Current Folder tool since R2014b.

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial tools that can perform a diff of Simulink models, some can even merge them too.  The Mathworks tool was mentioned in the comments of another answer, but there are other tools such as [SimDiff](http://www.ensoftcorp.com/simdiff/) that can [integrate with Git directly](http://www.ensoftcorp.com/simdiff/repository/Git_Integration_SD4.pdf).

*Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes SimDiff*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you highlight or point out what are the differences between SimDiff and the MathWorks tool beside the git direct integration? Is there a Student Version? 
Thanks

Comment: SimDiff has been on the market since 2005, which I think is earlier than the Mathworks tool.  Speed and accuracy has always been a point of emphasis for SimDiff.  One significant advantage is that MATLAB doesn't need to be opened to perform a diff, which can save time and avoid using a MATLAB license.

Comment: As far as a student license, I don't think we currently have one but students may instead be eligible for extended trial periods.  But you should probably [contact sales](http://www.ensoftcorp.com/company/#ContactUs) to confirm that; I'm not up to date on the latest policies.

Answer (score 0):

[DiffPlug](https://www.diffplug.com/features/simulink) is a free git client with native support for Simulink.  Diffing models isn't free, but you can view them from history for free.